# Why is my FreeTypeFont coming out blurry?

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, freetype

The font I'm using looks nice and sharp in the script but when I use it in my game it's extremely blurry and hard to see. How do I make it sharp?

Here's my code for it:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Fonts/Blenda Script.otf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 8;
BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter); 
generator.dispose();
Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK);
```

I'm using an open type script that contains different sizes. I tried making the size match ones in the script so it wouldnt have to stretch but it still comes out blurry. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From the example you provided, your parameter size is 8 pixels, which is tiny. Try increasing the value and see if it looks better. I calculate my font sizes based on screen width and one of my normal fonts is `screenWidth*0.06`, which even with a small 480 resolution comes out to a font size of 28.

Comment: Yeah when I increase the size the quality improves, but I needed this font to represent the amount of ammo and I wanted it to only occupy a small space. I ended up increasing the size and then scaling down.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the size was too small so I increased the size and then scaled down the font to the size I wanted.